# Odd problem with IE8 and z-index CSS property

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I not been able to put one DIV over his parent DIV in Internet Explorer.
With Firefox is working as suposed to.

The odd part is that if I open the html file directly in IE, everything works fine.
But if I upload to the server and open from there, the div is hidden underneath his parent.

I've tried several z-index combinations and none works.

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">

.col { float:left; width:310px; margin-right:13px; }

.art { position:relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0; font: normal normal bold 11px Arial,Verdana,Helvetica; color:#A0A0A0; width:310px; height:50px; top:0px; left: 0px; margin-right:10px; background-color:#F0F0F0; }
.art a  { padding:3px; display:block; width:304px; height:100%; color:#707070; }
.art a:visited { color:#A0A0A0; }
.art a:hover { background-color:#E0E0E0; }

.box { z-index:1000; background-color:#A0A0A0; color:#404040; font: normal normal bold 11px Arial,Verdana,Helvetica; display:none; position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px; text-align:left; border:3px solid #707070; margin:5px 0px 5px 5px; font-size:10px; color:White; width:100%; }

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function sh(obj) 
{
  var el = document.getElementById(obj);
  if ( el.style.display != 'block' )   {
    el.style.display = 'block'; 
  }
  else 
  {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="col">


<div class="art">
<a href="" target="_blank" onmouseover="javascript:sh('i0')" onmouseout="javascript:sh('i0')">Title 1</a>

<div id="i0" class="box">
<div class="text">
Les "chemises rouges" manifestent depuis la mi-mars pour faire tomber le gouvernement et occupent depuis trois semaines un quartier touristique et commerçant autour duquel ils ont érigé des barricades.
</div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="art">

<a href="" target="_blank" onmouseover="javascript:sh('i1')" onmouseout="javascript:sh('i1')">Title2</a>

<div id="i1" class="box">
<div class="text">
Une association ardéchoise accueillant des séminaires de "bien-être" et de "développement personnel" a refusé d'accueillir un stage de danse en invoquant l'homosexualité des participants, ont indiqué aujourd'hui les organisateurs.
</div>
</div>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I think different stacking contexts are in play here. Z-index and positioning can be tricky:

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Comment: Yes, there's lot of information on the web with this kind of problems using IE6-7.
In this case, it's peculiar because if you create an HTML file with this code and open directly in the browser it will work.
But if you upload to a server, it will not...
Also this kind of problems should be resolved in IE8.

Comment: @DK39, "Also this kind of problems should be resolved in IE8." Dare I suggest that so long as there is IE so too will there be IE bugs and associated craziness.